# How to calculate $\int _{\gamma }e^{e^{z}+z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

$z=re^{i\theta_{0} }$ and $\gamma \left( t\right) =re^{it\theta _{0}}$  $0\leq t\leq 1$ How to calculate $\int _{\gamma }e^{e^{z}+z}dz$ this integral?
I tried $e^{z}=w$ then result $e^{e^{z}}$ but i couldn't finish. Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure analytic solution exists?

Comment: Does $\theta_0$ have a specific known value? If it happens that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$ then the integral is zero. since the integrand is analytic.

Comment: $z=re^{\theta_0}$ makes no sense in this context. You are integrating over $z.$

Comment: Note that $e^{e^z + z}\;dz = e^{e^z}\cdot e^z\;dz = e^w\;dw$

Comment: @MPW okey but i have no idea boundary of integral i have tried something then integral result $e^{e^{z}}$ Does it end here or continuation?

Comment: Are you sure you want to integrate $\exp(z+\exp z)$ over an arc of a circle and not over a whole circle?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need any substitution:
$$ \exp(z+\exp z)=\frac{d}{dz}\exp(\exp z) $$
and you are integrating an entire function over an arc of a circle. The outcome just depends on the values of $\exp\exp z$ at the endpoints.

Comment: lower bound is ''r'' and upper bound is ''z''. how did  go far?